# Print translated links in custom page--front.tpl.php

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I have a custom template for my front page, where I have to manually set URLs. Some of them are Views paths (such as `news`), some - aliased node URLs (`projects/project-1`). How to get their path translation URL in raw PHP code?

If I say something like:

`<a href="<?php print url('news', array('language'=> $langcode, 'alias' => TRUE)) ?>" ...></a>`

the rendered link is invalid langauge-crossed, such as `mysite.com/es/news`.

I tried also with the [l()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function but I'm getting untranslated link pointing to the root `mysite.com/news`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an obvious answer to experts, but hopefully this will help some newbie someday. I painstakingly investigated the url stuff in Drupal and my findings surprised me - especially when I referred them to the docs.

In the tpl I placed the following nasty debug lines:

```
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('alias-en')) ?>
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('alias-en', 'es')) ?>
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('alias-en', 'en')) ?>
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('en/alias-en')) ?>
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('/en/alias-en')) ?>
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('es/alias-es')) ?>
<?php dpm(drupal_get_normal_path('/es/alias-es')) ?>
```

And the results were:

```
alias-en
alias-en
node/298
en/alias-en
/en/alias-en
es/alias-es
/es/alias-es
```

Only the third result `(node/298)` was returned as desired, good for passing to `i18n_get_path_translations`. Even though the `drupal_get_normal_path()` function docs say the language parameter is optional, and subsequently called `drupal_lookup_path()` is said to put current language if NULL is passed, it does not seem to work this way.

`drupal_get_normal_path()` seems to require that you pass two parameters: alias and the language the alias is set for. Only then you'll get the result that will work reliably with `i18n_get_path_translations`.

I'm close to thinking it is a bug in Drupal or docs, and if no one sheds light on me, I'm going to file an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `l` function with `language` options to protect links against language prefix, like this one `mysite/en/node/etc/1` for example:

```
<?php print l(t('title'), $path, array('language' => 'en')); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this produces untranslated href, only the link text is translated.

Comment: I just found this http://drupal.org/project/multilink and will give it a try.

Comment: good luck and good night ) its too late